# Ansible Increment Number on each node

Tags: ansible, numbers, increment

I'am trying to define the jvmroute in server.xml of tomcat by naming it node0x.
To do that i find i playbook with increment_number with anisble_facts

```
`     - name: set number node
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: "{{env}}adm"
      set_fact:
         node_number: 1

    - name: Nommage des nodes
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: "{{env}}adm"
      community.general.xml:
        path: /data/{{env}}/web/tomcat/conf/server.xml
        xpath: /Server/Service/Engine
        attribute: jvmroute
        value: "node0{{node_number}}"
        backup: true
      when: load_balancing == "yes"

    - name: increment number node
      become: yes
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: "{{env}}adm"
      set_fact:
         node_number={{ node_number | int + 1 }}`

and calling this task like this

`- name: set count
  set_fact:
    node_number: 1

- name: Nommages des nodes tomcat
  include_tasks: nommage_nodes.yml
  with_items: "{{hostlb}}"
  when: not resultchrono.stat.exists`
```

What i want is on server1 define node01, then server2 define node02 etc..

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **"On server1 define node01, then server2 define node02 etc."**

A: For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

Get indexes and create the names of the variables

```yaml
    my_index: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
    my_node_var: my_node_{{ my_index }}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] =>
  my_node_var: my_node_1
ok: [test_02] => 
  my_node_var: my_node_2
ok: [test_03] => 
  my_node_var: my_node_3
```

Set the values

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_node_{{ my_index }}: 1
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  lookup('vars', my_node_var): '1'
ok: [test_02] => 
  lookup('vars', my_node_var): '1'
ok: [test_03] => 
  lookup('vars', my_node_var): '1'
```

Increment the variable if you want to

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_node_{{ my_index }}: "{{ lookup('vars', my_node_var) + 1 }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  lookup('vars', my_node_var): '1'
ok: [test_02] => 
  lookup('vars', my_node_var): '1'
ok: [test_03] => 
  lookup('vars', my_node_var): '1'
```

Reference the variable

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_node_1
      when: inventory_hostname == 'test_01'
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  my_node_1: '2'
skipping: [test_02]
skipping: [test_03]
```

, or use *hostvars* to reference any of the variables

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          my_node_1: "{{ hostvars.test_01.my_node_1 }}"
          my_node_2: "{{ hostvars.test_02.my_node_2 }}"
          my_node_3: "{{ hostvars.test_03.my_node_3 }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    my_node_1: "2"
    my_node_2: "2"
    my_node_3: "2"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_index: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) + 1 }}"
    my_node_var: my_node_{{ my_index }}
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_index
    - debug:
        var: my_node_var

    - set_fact:
        my_node_{{ my_index }}: 1
    - debug:
        var: lookup('vars', my_node_var)

    - set_fact:
        my_node_{{ my_index }}: "{{ lookup('vars', my_node_var) + 1 }}"
    - debug:
        var: lookup('vars', my_node_var)

    - debug:
        var: my_node_1
      when: inventory_hostname == 'test_01'

    - debug:
        msg: |
          my_node_1: "{{ hostvars.test_01.my_node_1 }}"
          my_node_2: "{{ hostvars.test_02.my_node_2 }}"
          my_node_3: "{{ hostvars.test_03.my_node_3 }}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: hi it is working but my inventory looks like
BDD
APP1
APP2
APP3
and i only want to run it on the APPs server
Or like this it count from BDD server as node01 then APP2 as node02 instead of count from APP1 as node01

Comment: You said: `What I want is on server1 to define node01, then server2 to define node02, etc`. What you describe in the above comment is a different use case. Open a new question on this and make it [mre].